# Ломается код через некоторое время python

Tags: python, requests

```
link = "ссылка"
check = "false"


def send_message(message):
    token = "токен"
    chat_id = "чат айди"
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text=<b>{message}</b>"
    requests.get(url).json()


def check_alert(alert):
    dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    global check

    if alert == "True" and check == "false":
        send_message(f"{dt} Сообщение какое-то")
        check = "true"
    elif alert == "False" and check == "true":
        send_message(f"{dt} Сообщение какое-то")
        check = "false"
    else:
        print(f"Сообщение какое-то= {alert}") #Type alert = False / Type alert = True
    get_alert()


def get_alert():
    while True:
        try:
            response = requests.get(link)
            response_json = response.json()
            typeAlert = response_json["states"]["...."]["enabled"]
        except Exception:
            time.sleep(300)

        time.sleep(5)
        check_alert(typeAlert)


get_alert()
```

Ломаю голову целый день(новичок)

Есть код(не спрашивайте какой в нем смысл, некоторую информацию, которая не играет роль - скрыл)

Я получаю данные через API через одну функцию. В ней вызываю вторую функцию, где проходит проверка полученного значения по API. Если значение равно тому то тому то - то выполняется определенные действия, одно из них - вызов третьей функции, где я передаю значение и потом это  же значение публикуется в телеграм канале. Заметьте, что функция get_alert() бесконечная(должна быть), т.е получаю данные каждые 5 секунд.

**Так вот, по началу все работает идеально, никаких нареканий нет, но потом через, возможно, минут 3-4 появляются ошибки(Traceback (most recent call last)), и в следствии чего, код стопается. Вот скрин:**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строки нет смысла считать, тут есть неважные абсолютно строчки кода, который я удалил.

**Надеюсь на вашу помощь и жду идеи, как решить проблему!!!!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDE печатает вам причину падения - `local variable 'typeAlert' referenced before assignment`

Ваша переменная `typeAlert` существует только внутри try / except. Измените ее [область видимости](https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/2.9.php). Например так

```
def get_alert():
while True:
    typeAlert = *что-то*
    try:
        response = requests.get(link)
        response_json = response.json()
        typeAlert = response_json["states"]["...."]["enabled"]
    except Exception:
        time.sleep(300)

    time.sleep(5)
    if typeAlert != *чему-то*:
       check_alert(typeAlert)
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую и напишу(надо немного пожождать). А еще тогда вопрос, а чего код сначала нормально все работает, а потом уже через некоторое время ошибка эта? Разве она не сразу должна появится?

Comment: Я не вижу часть кода отвечающую за отправку "Type alert = False", но она очевидно работает корректно. Как только код попадает в get_alert() он падает.

Comment: сейчас весь код кину, подредачу сообщение

Comment: затупил, уже есть это весь код. (добавил комментарий в нем)

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь! Вроде бы после изменения кода, как вы написали - ошибок пока нет. Но как ниже написал человек, возможно, через некоторое время выскочит и ошибка из-за лимита рекурсии(

Comment: Проблему с областью видимости мой ответ должен решить. Если вдруг произойдет еще падение - советую задать отдельный вопрос. Пишите в названии краткое содержание ошибки, а не общую фразу, также код падений лучше добавлять текстом, а не скриншотами. Правильное оформление ошибки поможет найти желающих помочь, а также избежать преждевременного закрытия вопроса. [WIKI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) на эту тему. Если ответ на вопрос решает вашу проблему, не забывайте его принимать и оценивать. Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Предполагаю, что проблема в лимите рекурсии. Стандартный лимит рекурсии в python не более тысячи повторений.

У вас одна функция вызывает вторую и наоборот, и так по кругу. Всё работает какое-то время исправно, значит проблема вряд ли в переменных или мелочах.

Простой пример ошибки из-за лимита рекурсии:

```
def first():
    second()

def second():
    print('Проверка')
    first()
    
first()
```

Сначала код выполняется, затем выходит за лимит рекурсии и перестаёт.

Если данный пример изменить на:

```
def first():
    while True:
        second()

def second():
    print('Проверка')

first()
```

То всё будет работать бесконечно так, как это уже не рекурсия.

Я сам новичок, так что могу ошибаться, но предположение имеет место быть.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!)